# Why does my JavaScript OR statement not return the correct value?

Tags: javascript, operators, undefined, operator-precedence

I'm stuck with the following:

```
foo = properties[field] || overrides.default || config.widget.default || undefined;
```

with

```
console.log(properties[field])     // undefined
console.log(overrides.default)     // 0
console.log(config.widget.default) // undefined
```

So as I understand, `foo` should be `0`. Yet... it's `undefined`

This still works:

```
foo = properties[field] || overrides.default;
```

But as soon as I add another OR option, it does not work anymore.

**Question**:
Why is my 2nd operand with `value=0` not overriding the `undefined` operands?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `||` operator returns its left-hand operand if it is truthy, otherwise it returns the right-hand operand.

In your example, all operands have falsey values, so the compound `||` statement returns the right-most value.

In JS, the following are all falsey: `0`, `""` (empty string), `undefined`, `null`, `NaN`. And of course `false`. All other values are truthy (including strings like `"0"` or `"false"` because they're not empty strings).

Comment: is it because `0` is a falsey value, too?